# Why isn't NSMutableArray working?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have a NSMutableArray of a class, and in other class I'd like to initialize it and add various objects. But the problem is that the NSMutableArray isn't retaining the elements. I have the following code:

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad
  {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    MyStops *myStops = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"My Stops"];
    myStops.myStopsMArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  }
```

And this one:

```
- (void) addToFavourites:(id)sender 
  {
    UITapGestureRecognizer *gesture = (UITapGestureRecognizer *) sender;

    NSInteger tag = gesture.view.tag;

    UITableViewCell *cell = [stopsTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    MyStops *myStops = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Mis Paradas"];

    [myStops.myStopsMArray addObject:[stopsArray objectAtIndex:tag]];
 }
```

And in the other file I have the NSMutableArray declared and synthesized:

```
//Header file
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *myStopsMArray;

//Implementation file
@synthesize myStopsMArray;
```

Can you tell me please what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` creates and returns NEW INSTANCE every time! 
So you must have a direct pointer to that view controller. 
In the header file of your current class make a property like:

`@property (strong, nonatomic) MyStops *myStopsVC;`

NOTE: 
Change `strong` to `weak` if your current ViewController already presented from `MyStops`. But if you're going to push/present MyStops from this vc, then keep it as `strong` pointer.

Comment: so in `addToMyFavourites` I should have this: `self.myStopsVC.myStopsMArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self.myStopsVC.myStopsMArray addObject:[stopsArray objectAtIndex:tag]];`, right?

Comment: Yes. But before creating new array you must check if it's created already or not. If not, then create it, e.g. `if (!self.myStopsVC.myStopsMArray) 
{self.myStopsVC.myStopsMArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];}`.
Otherwise it will create new instance every time when you click on addFavorite button and all previously added favorites will be erased :)

Comment: I must to be a completely stupid, but it still doesn't work… :S

Comment: What is your case? This current view controller is presented from MyStops,  or it must present MyStops?

Answer (score 0):

You have two distinct instances of your `MyStops` ViewController, that's why.

In you `viewDidLoad`,  you create a `MyStops` ViewController then 
`alloc`/`init` its "`myStopsMArray`" `NSMutableArray`.

But in you `addToFavorites` method, you create **another, different and brand new**  `MyStops` instance — for which you didn't `alloc`/`init` you `myStopsMArray` property. Hence in that method, `myStops.myStopsMArray` is still `nil`.

Comment: And what do you recommend to do?

Comment: Don't create a separate instance if you don't need one. Especially, I don't really understand why you need to instantiate ce ViewController from the Storyboard… in the `viewDidLoad` method?! — your original question is unclear which class this `viewDidLoad` implementation is from, I hope it's not you `MyStops` view controller itself 'cause that wouldn't make sense… but I'm not sure you clearly understand what you are doing? And why do you need to create that instance in the viewDidLoad if it is to store it in a local variable that you won't use anywhere in your method?

Comment: I think maybe you did write that code in `viewDidLoad` just to try and hoping it would work without understanding why. When a ViewController is created, its `viewDidLoad` will eventually get called once it needs to display its view on screen. So calling `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` which will create an instance of your VC, will eventually lead iOS to call this VC's `viewDidLoad` method, so calling `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` in `viewDidLoad` itself doesn't make sense. The method you probably intended to override is `init`, `initWithCoder:` or `awakeFromNib`.